# (Chrome Extension) How to focus on the omnibox when you create a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that redirects you to a specific url every time you open a new tab. The code I'm using is down below. However it is really annoying that whenever I open a new tab, it does it's job in redirecting me to the url but **it does not highlight the omnibox**!! This means it really frustrating to do my searches as this address bar is not highlighted. I know Control + L is an option but we are all so used to not doing this.

When I open a new tab, I can see the omnibox being highlighted but then it it goes away right afterwards. Is there a way keep this address bar highlighted before, during and after the redirect?

I know this is possible because this extension, [Tab for a cause](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-for-a-cause/gibkoahgjfhphbmeiphbcnhehbfdlcgo?hl=en) redirects you to their custom url **while still keeping the onmibox highlighted**!!

Thank you in advance!

I'm using manifest version 2.

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "...",
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "my.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
    ]
}
```

`my.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>    
    </body>
</html>
```

`code.js`

```
window.location.href = "https://website-of-interest.com/"
```

Comment: As you can see in the code of that extension, it uses chrome.tabs.update.